# Phaser and Web Audio API - orientate sprite

Tags: javascript, audio, vector, sprite, phaser-framework

I'm trying to use phaser with the web audio API but I can't figure out how to go from the sprites x, y, z and rotation values to a directional vector and up vector. How would I do this?

```js
ctx.setPosition(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.z);
ctx.setOrientation(0,0,0,0,0,0);
ctx.setVelocity(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I worked it out, here's the code:

```
function updateWithSprite(sprite)
    if (sprite.body) {
        var rot = sprite.body.rotation + Math.PI / 2;
        this.setPosition(sprite.body.x, body.y, 0);
        this.setOrientation(Math.cos(rot), Math.sin(rot), 0);
        this.setVelocity(sprite.body.velocity.x, sprite.body.velocity.y, sprite.body.velocity.z);
    } else {
        var rot = sprite.rotation + Math.PI / 2;
        this.setPosition(sprite.x, sprite.y, 0);
        this.setOrientation(Math.cos(rot), Math.sin(rot), 0);
        this.setVelocity(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```